# Queries to get all ancestors/descendents of a tree in a db?

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

I have a table `(id, parent_id, data)` where `parent_id` points to another row in same table (or is null).

Is there a standard way to query (1) all the ancestors of a certain id and (2) all the descendants of a certain id?

I'm also doing this in `DBIx::Class`, so if there's a most convenient way to do it with that module (or some other), I'd love to hear about that as well.

EDIT: clarify - all parents = all ancestors, all children = all descendants.

Comment: Just parents/children, or all ancestors/descendants? Also, which flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: Looking to be somewhat SQL agnostic; our development db is SQLite, but production will probably be MySQL.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like we're going to go with [`DBIx::Class::Tree::AdjacencyList`](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/DBIx-Class-Tree-0.03001/lib/DBIx/Class/Tree/AdjacencyList.pm) at the moment.  It does *almost* everything I was looking for (no ancestors resultset, unfortunately - but we can work around that by approaching the questions we need to ask from the other direction).

However, @Grrrr's answer got me thinking, and we may add a separate table + module `(id, record_type, record_ancestors)` that would attach to our models that have a `parent_id` column and provide an `ancestors` resultset (basically by doing a search_rs where the id is in the split of the relevant ancestors row by w/e delimiter we pick).  That's a fair bit of work just to get such a result set, so we'll probably only go there if we find questions where it's really impractical to ask "is this a child of parent x" and really need "is this a parent of child x"?

EDIT: or maybe we'll use [`DBIx::Class::Tree::Mobius`](http://search.cpan.org/~vdg/DBIx-Class-Tree-Mobius-0.00002_01/lib/DBIx/Class/Tree/Mobius.pm) - though it looks like viewing the table raw would be incomprehensible.

Comment: It would be very easy for you to add an `ancestors` method to your Row classes, either by adding it directly into your `Result` classes or by creating a new Component that subclasses AdjacencyList and adds the method you need. Or perhaps you could stop by #dbix-class and have a chat with us about just adding the feature to AdjacencyList itself; it seems like a pretty reasonable thing to have.

Comment: @hobbs: my collaborator on this project offered up a patch adding an ancestors resultset to AdjacencyList (not sure what id he posts under, and he doesn't have enough SO rep to make his own comment).

Answer (score 3):

This highly depends on the flavor of SQL you are using.

In Oracle, you can use the `START WITH id = yourid CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id` construct. In PostgreSQL, you can use a function `connectby('tablename', 'id', 'parent_id', 'id', value, 0)`.

In many cases, it makes sense to represent trees
differently, by defining a column which will hold,
for every node, a complete path from the root element
to this node.

There are plenty examples of this technique
to be found on the Internet, the most recent one I saw,
which also deals with [`DBIx::Class`](http://p3rl.org/DBIx::Class), can be found here: http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2010/05/threaded-forum-sql.html

Comment: One of things I'm regularly doing with this tree is relocating nodes within the tree structure.  That seems vaguely painful re having a column that stores the whole ancestor list.  I guess overloading the update to do that correctly wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: eeeeeh...except for the cascading part.